# Assign variable to mysql query ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra

So I'm building a login/signup page in Ruby/Sinatra, and I'm trying to add some logic so that if someone tries to sign up with an email that is in use, it will tell them so, and not allow them to sign up

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'mysql'

get "/" do
        erb :form
end

post "/" do

begin
        con = Mysql.new('localhost', 'tut', 'tut', 'recruited_users')
        auth = con.query('SELECT school FROM users WHERE email = "#{params[:email]}" AND password = "#{params[:password]}"')
        auth.fetch_row
        ensure
                con.close if con
        end
end

get '/signup' do
        erb :signup
end

post '/signup' do

begin
        con = Mysql.new('localhost', 'tut', 'tut', 'recruited_users')
        check_for_user = con.query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '#{params[:email]}'")
        if check_for_user == ''
                "Sorry, but there is already an account for this user. The ID is '#{params[:check_for_user]}', please try again"
        else
                auth = con.query("INSERT INTO users (email, password, school) VALUES('#{params[:email]}', '#{params[:password]}', '#{params[:school]}')")
                "Succesfully created user #{params[:email]}"
        end
        ensure
                con.close if con
        end
end
```

The problem is that the variable `check_for_user` is not receiving any value, at least not one that I can work with. I need to be able to set up the if statement so that they can only create a new user if the email does not already exist in the database.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is making you choose raw SQL rather than an ORM like sequel or datamapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can't use string interpolation (`#{...}`) inside a single quoted string, that only works with double quoted strings (or things like `%Q{...}` that behave like double quoted strings). Secondly, string literals in SQL should be quoted with single quotes, MySQL and SQLite let you get away with double quotes but that's a bad habit. Thirdly, we're not hacking PHP in 1999 so you shouldn't be using string interpolation to build SQL, you should use placeholders:

```
sth = con.prepare('select school from users where email = ? and password = ?')
sth.execute(params[:email], params[:password])
row = sth.fetch
if(!row)
    # Didn't find anything
else
    # The school is in row.first
end
```

Comment: In addition, the user could enter their string in a different letter-case than the initial email address. The case-sensitive search would return a miss, but folding to the same case in the database and the search, would return a hit.

Comment: I tried the above code, and I'm still not getting the right result. Is there something I need to do to use the ? placeholder?

Comment: @bwheeler96: what does "not working" mean? Any errors or exceptions? Do you have a case problem as Tin Man noted? Have you tried your queries in the `mysql` tool?